# CSS Grid Item with full browser width background color?

Tags: css, layout, grid, css-grid

I try to jump intro CSS Grids now! But one thing isn't clear to me. How would you build a master grid/layout, where maybe your header, hero and footer background color got full browser width (like stackoverflow header/footer)? Without nesting divs like you would do today with flexbox, floats & co. Is that possible in a clean way? I hope you understand what I try to get working. I added an image, maybe that makes it clearer ;)

[image]

okay here is a fiddle:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Grid Layout Test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="topbar">
      <div class="logo">LOGO</div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">Menu Item</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Menu Item #2</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Menu Item #3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="hero">
      <p class="hero-text">Hero Banner</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <h1 class="content-headline">Content</h1>
      <p class="content-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis
        natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque
        eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget,
        arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
        Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula,
        porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus.
        Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue.
        Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus,
        sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit
        id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis
        ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales
        sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nun</p>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar">
      <h2 class="sidebar-headline">Sidebar</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
      <p class="footer-text">Footer</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box
    }

    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    }

    .container {
      display: grid;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1000px;
      grid-template-areas: "topbar topbar topbar" "hero hero hero" "content content sidebar" "footer footer footer";
    }

    .topbar {
      grid-area: topbar;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
      background-color: darkolivegreen;
      color: white;
      padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .topbar ul {
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .hero {
      grid-area: hero;
      background-color: lightcoral;
      min-height: 300px;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center center;
    }

    .sidebar {
      grid-area: sidebar;
      width: 200px;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }

    .footer {
      grid-area: footer;
      background-color: darkgoldenrod;
    }
  </style>

</body>

</html>
```

But now I want the background colors of topbar, hero and footer to be full browser size without the need to work with classical nesting divs arround my areas. If I would have to do this, I don't see any benefits of css grids for overall layouts.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: heres a fiddle. thought that would be imagineable because of my sketch.

Comment: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/breaking-out-with-css-grid-layout/

Comment: This is what I meant!! Thank you @Paulie_D!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a certain HTML layout with a container that will force certain elements to stay within a set width. Anything outside of the container will then be displayed as full width.

Here's a live [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/n6gbLdxo/2/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Set width content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Set width content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <!-- Full width content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you for help! but that would be the same old non-css-grid-way from the years before css grid in my opinion. because I had to define a grid for every section container itself. I can't go with an whole CSS Grid layout without nesting and nesting and nesting...

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. So, you're unable to wrap your grid into a container?

Comment: no ;) I just thought this could be avoided with css grid. I thought I could avoid to write so many "useless" containers. But maybe I just had wrong expectations about css grid. The only thing thats missing in my imagination is, to let background colors, background images and anything like that to "bust out" of the row to be full browser width. that would make my markup and css much cleaner.

Comment: Ah, alright. No, a `grid` is indeed only used to achieve a layout directly within a set area. There's no magic that could simply squeeze child elements within their parents without adding a wrapper somewhere (as far as I know).

Comment: Hence my answer.

Comment: Okay, that's the right answer :) I just thought I was missing something. Thank you @Levano!!